# Selecting radio buttons with Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on a Kendo UI grid. I have a grid which contains data from an external source. Also I have a radio button assigned to each row as a template.

How can I make the radio button select when I click a row? Currently, I have to click on the radio button to make it selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a checkbox instead, and here is how I am defining it.

```
columns.Bound(x => x.IsChecked).ClientTemplate(
   "<input name='IsChecked' class='chkBox' type='checkbox'
     data-bind='checked: IsChecked' #= IsChecked ? checked='checked' : '' #/>");
```

And then on click function of the grid

```
    $('#Grid').click(function () {

        var gview = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());                     
        var bool = selectedItem.IsChecked;
        selectedItem.set("IsChecked", (bool) ? 0 : 1);    
        console.log(selectedItem); 

        //This is what you need to do to keep the row selected.
        gview.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + selectedItem.uid + "']")
        .addClass("k-state-selected");      

    })
```

If you view the `selectedItem` in the console, you will see that kendo adds a `uid` property. 
So we are findind that `uid` and adding the `k-state-selected` class.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am still working on the same issue. In my case, I can select the row but radio button still stays de-selected. One more thing, I am using kendo UI with angularjs.

Comment: See my edit, I'm not using angular here, but at least try to copy and past my code on a fresh Grid or something so this way you can at least see the functionality working. Then you'll probably be able to mold what you need.

Comment: This doesn't work as intended with a radio button. A radio button only allows 1 value to be selected, my implementation by itself won't work with a radio button. Is there any reason why you are using a radio? If you use a checkbox instead this will work.

Comment: I can't use check box. Coz my application requires filtration depending upon the selection made by the user. Basically, I have master and detail grid in which the information in detail grid changes according the selection in master grid.

Comment: Ok so I'm curious why you need a radio button in the first place. If only 1 rb can be selected, and you have a radio button per grid row, what is the radio button handling that the default single grid selection can't?

Comment: you are right, rb are actually doing nothing here, all the work is doing by selected row, but here, I have to follow the design from the designer. I guess this is the way to give the visual effect to the user after they made selection

Comment: The highlight of the selected row is plenty of visual effect. If you think my answer was useful you can upvote it or mark as answer

Comment: your answer totally makes sense, I marked it as answer but cannot upvote it because of not having enough reputation. Any way thanks alot for sharing your knowledge